# Jest testing console log with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm attempting to test whether or not a function logs to the console. This is my current code being tested with Jest.

```
const func = require('./func');

test('should print to the console', async () => {
  console.log = jest.fn();
  await func('text.txt');
  expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(func);
});
```

Func reads from text.txt, does stuff with the stream and console logs separate lines at the end. It doesn't return anything. Am I using async/await the wrong way? Am I misunderstanding how streams work?

Comment: Can you include the code of `func`? Is `func` defined using the `async` keyword?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. `func` was a function that used `readline` to do stuff with data from a file. I resolved it by turning it into a promise.